# MySQL crash periodically with Operating system error number 203

Tags: mysql, crash

currently im running my project with mysql and periodically got crash (3-4days once). here my sql-error log :

```
2021-12-17 21:03:08 38140 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for reading partial data failed.
2021-12-17 21:03:08 38140 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 5750784, but was only able to read 0
2021-12-17 21:03:08 38140 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2021-12-17 21:03:08 38140 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2021-12-17 21:03:08 38140 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 403. Cannot continue operation
211217 21:03:08 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=24
max_threads=65537
thread_count=9
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 20294 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x1c7d3aa3788
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
ucrtbase.dll!raise()
ucrtbase.dll!abort()
mysqld.exe!?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@QEBD_K@Z()
mysqld.exe!?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@QEBD_K@Z()
mysqld.exe!?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@QEBD_K@Z()
mysqld.exe!?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@QEBD_K@Z()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@QEBD_K@Z()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!?assign@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QEAAAEAV12@QEBD_K@Z()
mysqld.exe!?ha_rnd_next@handler@@QEAAHPEAE@Z()
mysqld.exe!?rr_sequential@@YAHPEAUREAD_RECORD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?sub_select@@YA?AW4enum_nested_loop_state@@PEAVJOIN@@PEAUst_join_table@@_N@Z()
mysqld.exe!?disjoin@?$List@VItem@@@@QEAAXPEAV1@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?exec_inner@JOIN@@QEAAXXZ()
mysqld.exe!?exec@JOIN@@QEAAXXZ()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_select@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAUTABLE_LIST@@IAEAV?$List@VItem@@@@PEAVItem@@IPEAUst_order@@434_KPEAVselect_result@@PEAVst_select_lex_unit@@PEAVst_select_lex@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?handle_select@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@PEAULEX@@PEAVselect_result@@K@Z()
mysqld.exe!?execute_init_command@@YAXPEAVTHD@@PEAUst_mysql_lex_string@@PEAUst_mysql_rwlock@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_execute_command@@YAHPEAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_parse@@YAXPEAVTHD@@PEADIPEAVParser_state@@_N3@Z()
mysqld.exe!?dispatch_command@@YA_NW4enum_server_command@@PEAVTHD@@PEADI_N3@Z()
mysqld.exe!?do_command@@YA_NPEAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?pool_of_threads_scheduler@@YAXPEAUscheduler_functions@@PEAKPEAI@Z()
mysqld.exe!?tp_callback@@YAXPEAUTP_connection@@@Z()
ntdll.dll!TpReleaseWait()
ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeResource()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0x1c7d3c14580): SELECT *
FROM `lab`
WHERE `notif` = '0'
AND `status` = 'Sampling'
Connection ID (thread ID): 38140
Status: NOT_KILLED

Optimizer switch:     index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on,index_merge_sort_intersection=off,engine_condition_pushdown=off,index_condition_pushdown=on,derived_merge=on,derived_with_keys=on,firstmatch=on,loosescan=on,materialization=on,in_to_exists=on,semijoin=on,partial_match_rowid_merge=on,partial_match_table_scan=on,subquery_cache=on,mrr=off,mrr_cost_based=off,mrr_sort_keys=off,outer_join_with_cache=on,semijoin_with_cache=on,join_cache_incremental=on,join_cache_hashed=on,join_cache_bka=on,optimize_join_buffer_size=on,table_elimination=on,extended_keys=on,exists_to_in=on,orderby_uses_equalities=on,condition_pushdown_for_derived=on,split_materialized=on,condition_pushdown_for_subquery=on,rowid_filter=on,condition_pushdown_from_having=on

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file at D:\xampp\mysql\data\
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-12-17 21:04:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-12-17 21:04:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-12-17 21:04:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-12-17 21:04:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-12-17 21:04:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-12-17 21:04:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-12-17 21:04:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-12-17 21:04:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=1963810483
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB.     Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 1963810492; transaction id 1677404
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.4.11-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2021-12-17 21:04:07 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 211217 21:04:07
```

i go search for Operating system error number 203 and didn't get any useful tips to handle it.
how can i solved this problem? anyone can assist me how to troubleshooting this problem?

Thanks,

Regard,

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
OS Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please post text results of SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'lab'; for analysis.

Comment: i have solved this problem, the main reason is because broken harddrive. after i change to new one, the problem disappear. thanks

Comment: Congratulatons.  Wishing you a GREAT 2023.  View profile for contact info.